# cordova build ios hangs after "build settings from configuration file"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build

After "cordova build ios", the command hangs (runs forever) in the terminal. only thing I can do is stop it manually. if I remove the platform (cordova platform rm ios) and then add it again, it builds correctly until the end. but if I build the xcode project and make some modifications in the code and try to build it again, it hangs. I am using cordova v 6.3.1 and xcode 8.0. These are the lines after which it hangs:

```
CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2
```

sometimes I get code signing error instead of the hanging. I'm guessing it's something about Xcode. Just started with a clean install of the os (so a clean install of Xcode) and I suppose I skipped some settings or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem solved. It was because of iCloud Drive. I kept my cordova project in my Documents folder, which is synced with iCloud Drive. I don't know exactly why cordova doesn't work from iCloud Drive, so if anyone knows and can shed some light on this matter, be my guest ;)

Comment: I was getting this same problem and your answer gave me the solution; which was, in my case, that the cordova project was on an external drive, and moving it to the HD of the Mac got the build to work.  I'm afraid I cannot shed any light onto why that should be.